# Not able to deploy bar file using Ant

Tags: ant, messagebroker

I am getting an error when I am trying to execute the below piece of code:

```
 <target depends="" description="Deploys to the selected MQSI broker." name="MQSI-cvs-deploy-broker_QA">
    <echo message="Deploying to MQSI broker using broker.properties file..."/>
    <echo/>
    <echo message="Broker: ${release.broker.name}"/>
    <echo/>
    <property file="${release.working.dir}/${product.code}/broker.properties"/>
    <echo message ="${release.working.dir}/${product.code}/broker.properties"/>

    <propertycopy name="release.execgroup.names" from="${environment.code}.execgroup.names"/>
    <foreach list="${release.execgroup.names}" inheritall="true" target="MQSI-cvs-deploy-execgroup_QA" param="release.execgroup.name"/>
</target>

<!-- This target deploys to the MQSI execution group(s) selected in cvs-deploy-broker-MQSI -->
<target depends="" description="Deploys to the selected MQSI execution groups." name="MQSI-cvs-deploy-execgroup_QA">
    <echo message="Deploying to MQSI broker's execution group..."/>
    <echo/>
    <echo message="Execgroup: ${release.execgroup.name}"/>
    <inputstring username="${mqsiqa.server.deploy.username}" password="${mqsiqa.server.deploy.password}" host="10.202.79.36" verifyhost="false" >

    </inputstring>

    <exec dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\MQSI\9.0.0.3\bin" executable="cmd.exe"  failonerror="true">
                <arg line="mqsideploy"/>
                <arg value="-n" />
                <arg value="${release.broker.name}" />
                <arg value="-e" />
                <arg value="${release.execgroup.name}" />
                <arg value="-a" />
                <arg value="${release.bar.file}" />
                <arg value="-w" />
                <arg value="90" />
            </exec>

</target>
```

This is the error message:

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\Build\Build.2.0\antDeploy.xml:356: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Build\Build.2.0\antDeploy.xml:364: Problem: failed to create task or type inputstring
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: which version of ant are you using?

Comment: Where does it say that <inputstring> is a valid item in an ant-target? Is this element defined in any particular jar?